# AWS Route 53 https://example.com goes to blank page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have set up an S3 bucket to reroute all traffic to example.com to www.example.com with https according to this [very poor AWS guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/). It works for example.com and http://example.com.

But when I access https://example.com it hangs for a little while and then routes to a blank page. Why is it so difficult to redirect a URL I own to another one in AWS and how do I fix this?

Edit:
I am now configuring CloudFront distributions and trying to find one decent tutorial explaining how to perform this seemingly simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you miss this line in the link you provided:

Note: **The sites must use HTTP, because the redirect can't connect to Amazon S3 over HTTPS.**

You are trying to do something that is expliciting called out as not being possible in the docs.

BTW: If you want to use https to service static s3 websites, using cloudfront if often the easiest and quickest way to do that.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/

Comment: Wow, didn't think a guide could get worse than the one I linked but the one you linked certainly takes the cake. I didn't know it was possible to make a user interface as poor as Amazon CloudFront until I saw it with my own eyes.

Comment: Thanks E.J. Managed to figure it out. I appreciate the assistance and sorry if I was catty. Will be sure to read the notes next time I follow a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured this out and I am going to describe here what worked for me. E.J.'s answer above was a helpful pointer but wasn't specific enough to make this the absolutely trivial task I would hope this to be, even for a first-timer.

Here are the exact steps required, with some prior notes.

Two notes:

- You HAVE to setup an SSL certificate with AWS to re-route after https. As an organisation AWS has not yet reached the place where automatic certificate management is... well... automatic. You have to use what I might call AWS "Extremely Manual" ACM.
- You need an AWS S3 bucket (make it have the name of the domain your are routing FROM).

Steps:

1. Follow [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/) to setup a S3 bucket that will route (without HTTPs) from example.com to www.example.com (or vice versa I guess)
2. Navigate to the absolute eye-sore that is Amazon CloudFront
3. Click everywhere until you find a button to "create distribution"
4. Set "Origin Domain Name" to the link for the bucket created in step 1. DO NOT use the one AWS recommends, you have to go to the bucket and copy the end-point manually, the one AWS fills-in automatically will not work. It should look like this: `example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` but location and stuff will be different obviously. Not sure why AWS recommends the wrong end-point but that is the least of my concerns about this process.
5. [This guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/) works for the rest of the CloudFront distribution creation but is not super specific and points to [this mess](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/install-ssl-cloudfront/) at one important part. The other steps are okay but when creating an SSL certificate just click that "Request or Import a Certificate with ACM" button (you will have to refresh after creating a certificate because Ajax didn't exist when the AWS console was made 200 years ago)
6. And the most important step, take the link or whatever it is to your CloudFront distribution (which will look like this: `d328r8fyg.cloudfront.net`, this one is fake because apparently you're not supposed to share them), and make the A record for example.com created in step 1 point to that CF distro instead of pointing directly to your bucket.

And voila, only took about 3 hours to get a URL to redirect somewhere securely. Not sure why people expect us to make it to Mars when the largest company in the world can't point one url to another and Microsoft Image Editor still can't crop to a specific pixel dimension.

Anyway. I'm glad this is over.